# Stacking 4-D np arrays to get 5-D np arrays

Tags: python-3.x, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

For Python 3.9 and numpy 1.21.5, I have four 4-D numpy arrays:

```
x = np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=1.0, size=(5, 5, 7, 10))
y = np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=1.0, size=(5, 5, 7, 10))
z = np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=1.0, size=(5, 5, 7, 10))
w = np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=1.0, size=(5, 5, 7, 10))

x.shape, y.shape, z.shape, w.shape
# ((5, 5, 7, 10), (5, 5, 7, 10), (5, 5, 7, 10), (5, 5, 7, 10))
```

I want to stack them to get the **desired shape: (4, 5, 5, 7, 10)**.

The code that I have tried so far includes:

```
np.vstack((x, y, z, w)).shape
# (20, 5, 7, 10)

np.concatenate((x, y, z, w), axis=0).shape
# (20, 5, 7, 10)

np.concatenate((x, y, z, w)).shape
# (20, 5, 7, 10)
```

They seem to be doing (4 * 5, 5, 7, 10) instead of the **desired shape/dimension: (4, 5, 5, 7, 10)**

Help?

Comment: Use [`np.stack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html)

Answer (score 0):

The following code can get the expected shape:

```
np.array([x, y, z, w])         # shape --> (4, 5, 5, 7, 10)
```